# Каким образом можно продолжить проигрывание звукового потока после завершения звонка?

Tags: ios, аудио, swift4

Приложение проигрывает аудиофайл (в активном или в фоновом режиме). Поступает входящий звонок, проигрывание системой приостанавливается. Как  автоматически запустить снова проигрывание аудио сразу после завершения звонка?

UPD: эппловские документы на эту тему:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudiosession#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008240-CH1-DontLinkElementID_3

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudiosession/responding_to_audio_session_interruptions

из них получается такой код:

```
private func setupAudioSession() {
    do {

        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback, with: .mixWithOthers)
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)

        setupAudioNotifications()

    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}

private func setupAudioNotifications() {
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(handleInterruption), name: .AVAudioSessionInterruption, object: nil)
}

@objc func handleInterruption(notification: Notification) {

    guard let userInfo = notification.userInfo,
        let typeValue = userInfo[AVAudioSessionInterruptionTypeKey] as? UInt,
        let type = AVAudioSessionInterruptionType(rawValue: typeValue) else {
            return
    }

    if type == .began { // при звонке .began срабатывает всегда
        // Interruption began, take appropriate actions
        Player.shared.stop()

    } else if type == .ended { // а вот когда звонок заканчивается (любой из сторон), .ended не срабатывает 
        if let optionsValue = userInfo[AVAudioSessionInterruptionOptionKey] as? UInt {
            let options = AVAudioSessionInterruptionOptions(rawValue: optionsValue)
            if options.contains(.shouldResume) {
                // Interruption Ended - playback should resume
                Player.shared.start()
            } else {
                // Interruption Ended - playback should NOT resume
            }
        }
    }
}
```

но, если событие .began срабатывает всегда и плеер останавливается, то событие .ended по какой-то причине не срабатывает и команда плееру продолжить воспроизведение не уходит.

Tестирование происходит следующим образом: поступает входящий с другого телефона (при этом срабатывает .began), через несколько гудков на "исходящем" телефоне нажимается завершение вызова (в этом случае вызова handleInterruption уже не происходит)